# Fulltext search - Query equivalent to like

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to improve a query that uses like operator on a non indexed column. I've seached around and come up with fulltext search option.

I'm following this example
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes

here the steps taken:

```
CREATE TABLE `test.my_stopwords`(value VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;
INSERT INTO `test.my_stopwords`(`value`) VALUES ('admin');
INSERT INTO `test.my_stopwords`(`value`) VALUES ('journalist');

CREATE TABLE `test.Users` (
`Id` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
`Roles` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = 'test/my_stopwords';

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_users_role ON Users(Roles);
```

I'm trying to make a fulltext search equivalent to this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Users
WHERE Roles LIKE '%admin%' OR Roles LIKE '%journalist%';
```

Came up with this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Users
WHERE MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('admin journalist' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

here some possible values for Roles

```
'master_member allow_news system_user tradersclub system_admin'
'system_user system_admin tradersclub journalist mover'
'allow_news master_member system_user system_admin'
'allow_news system_user system_admin'
'master_member allow_news system_user system_admin system_collab tradersclub'
'system_user system_admin editor_scoop'
'master_member system_user journalist tradersclub'
'allow_news master_member system_user system_admin'
'system_user system_admin'
'allow_news master_member system_user system_admin'
'allow_news master_member system_user system_admin'
'allow_news system_user system_admin master_member system_collab tradersclub'
'system_user system_admin editor_scoop'
'system_user master_member system_admin'
'system_user system_admin tradersclub'
'system_admin system_user master_member tradersclub allow_news allow_ideas'
'system_user journalist master_member system_admin system_collab tradersclub allow_ideas allow_news support moderator c_manager influencer'
```

[image: like result]

[image: fulltext result]

The first return 128 rows and the second 19 rows. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? %admin% and %journalist% will find partial text. Stopwords should be ignored if I remember correctly.

Comment: @PeterKoltai added possible values for Roles

Comment: I think that full word 'admin' and 'journalist' are excluded from the second query, but not when 'admin' comes as a partial in a word, like 'system_admin'. The first query on the other hand will find 'system_admin' and 'anythin_admin' for %admin%

Comment: So the difference could be that the second one only finds 'admin' and 'journalist' when part of a word, but not when whole word; the the first returns everything similar.

Comment: But it should be equivalent right? Why this behavior would happen?

Comment: No because you excluded entire words admin and journalist from the fulltext search. Try without the stopword table and compare results.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I added 2 images with the results without the stopwords table. It is similar. I can't see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference how full-text boolean mode search and LIKE work when it comes to **wildcards**. I will use the 17 rows of data you provided with your question and for simplicity I restrict to one search phrase to show the difference.

- `Roles LIKE ('%admin%')` will return every row than contains `admin`, no
  matter, where it is found within the string in Roles column.
- `MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('journalist' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will only find rows that contain `journalist` exactly as one word.
- `MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('system*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will find rows that contain any word beginning with `system`.

Consider the following queries based on the above, made against your 17 rows of data:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Users
WHERE Roles LIKE ('%admin%');
```

The result will be **16**, because there is only one row (7th: `master_member system_user journalist tradersclub`) that does not contain `admin` somewhere in `Roles`.
Now, try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Users
WHERE MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('journalist' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It results **3**, you have 3 rows, that contain `journalist` as a whole word in `Roles`.
What about this one:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Users
WHERE MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('system*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Now you got **17**, because every row in your sample has at least one word in `Roles` that **begins with** `system`.

And here comes your problem: when working with full-text search in boolean mode **you cannot add a wildcard at the beginning of the word**. Check out this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE MATCH(Roles) AGAINST('*admin*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

One would expect to find rows that have some words **containing** `admin`, which you have many. **But in fact the above query results count 0**.

That's why you are you experiencing strange results with your approach.

In summary, **I think full text search is not meant for this kind of problem.** You have roles and users, and every user can have 0..n roles, and every role can be assigned to 0..n users. In relational databases this is a classical many-to-many relationship. You can have a table for roles, a table for users, and a join table that connects users to roles. This can make queries efficient when properly indexed.

Comment: I understand your point of view. The data has a bunch of problems, it's not normalized. I just have this "like" query that is not performing.

Comment: LIKE with leading and closing % will never perform well on large dataset, as I am sure you are also aware. If you use only closing %, it is much better but I think that does not solve your problem.